# How to migrate MVC3 application with EF4 to EF4.5

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-5

Can any one help me how to migrate EF4 to EF4.5 or 5?
Thanks

Comment: Can you explain your particular issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is:

1. Remove references to old EF version.
2. Add references to new EF version (nuget is the ideal source).
3. Compile.
4. Fix compile errors.

Comment: You forgot '0. install Visual Studio 2012 / .NET 4.5'

Comment: @hazzik. And -1 Install Windows.

Comment: thanks. nuget: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712906

Answer (score 1):

Julie Lerman has [a small screencast on her blog](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/video-entity-framework-5-enums-and-moving-solution-from-ef-4-3/) that shows how you can migrate a .NET 4 app with EF 4.3 to a .NET 4.5 app with EF 5.

The important thing to remember is, first update your project from .NET 4 to .NET 4.5 and update EF after that.

Comment: You don't have to upgrade to .NET 4.5 to use EF 4.3. Same applies to EF 5, though some features of EF5 only work with .NET 4.5.